# Revert style applied from focus after blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user focuses on a text field, I want that text in that text field to change colors (among several other properties). When the user leaves that field (blur), I want the text/style to appear as it was before the focus. Currently I am doing it in what seems to be a repetitious way.

```
$('#name1').focus(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red')
});
$('#name1').blur(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'black')
});
```

How would I do this something like:

```
$('#name1').blur(function() {
        $(this).beforeFocus();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a css style on how it should be on focus and remove it onblur.

```
.input_focus {
   color: red;
}
```

And the script,

```
$('#name1').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('input_focus')
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('input_focus')
});
```

This way you can add any number of style when focused.

Comment: Just be sure that `.input_focus` has enough precedence to override whatever style is being applied originally.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#name1').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
```

?

Comment: What if there are ten styles applied in the `focus`? I'm looking for a way to remove all the styles applied in the most DRY way.

Comment: use addClass() and removeClass() ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, I would use two different css classes and define all of the appropriate properties for those classes.  Then it would be something like this:

```
$('#name1').focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("blurred").addClass("focused");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("focused").addClass("blurred");
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to do it this way or if there are different values for different inputs, you could use `data`.

```
$('#name1').focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.data("oldColor", $this.css("color"))
         .css("color", "blue");

}).blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.css("color", $this.data("oldColor"));
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this line does: `var $this = $(this);`. Why can't you just use `$(this).data(...)` instead?

Comment: You can use `$(this)` but each time you use `$(this)` a call to jquery is made.  If you are going to use it multiple times it is better to save it to a variable and reuse it.  It's a small optimization.  Think of it as though you had a call to `getMyElement()` each time, you would probably just save it to a variable.  Same idea here.

Comment: @David542 It is better to cache jQuery objects instead of referring it as `$(this)` everywhere. If `$(this)` is used only once then there is no point in caching it.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Vega suggested, using `toggleClass()`:

```
$("#name1").focus(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("inpFocus");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("inpFocus");
});
```